# Submit Multiple Rows from Grid MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor-2

I am trying to add multiple objects from simple grid at one go. followed article http://www.donnfelker.com/editable-grid-list-binding-in-mvc2/
but probably missing some thing i cant figure out. In my controller i am getting null as items posted

View:

```
    @model List<ItemClass>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table>
        <thead>
            <th>PropertyA</th>
            <th>PropertyB</th>
        </thead>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        @(Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i], "TemplateName"))
    }
        </table>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit"></button>
    }
```

Edit Template for single item:

```
    @model ItemClass
    <tr>
        <td>
           @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.PropertyA)
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.PropertyB)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateItems(List<ItemClass> items)
    {
        //create in db
        return RedirectToAction("XXXXXX");
    }
```

Comment: <table> is in the parent view hosting this template. The out put HTML it generates has the table tags as desired

Comment: You are right about <tr>. I have tested with your code. It is posting model with collections. I can post the code if it helps.

Comment: Figured it out :)

The collection (`List<ItemClass>`) in Parent View is a property of model i am actually using. Changed the parameter name of `CreateItems(List<ItemClass> items)` to match the property name `CreateItems(List<ItemClass> itemsProperty)`. Just didn't mentioned parent view's model actually contains list as child property of model, for simplicity - in the end that came out to be the culprit... thanks for making me think beyond these lines of code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateItems(List<ItemClass> items)
    {


//       Impelement the for loop with the parameter items varialbe to store the values 
  //     in database 

       for(int i= 0 ; i<item.count; i ++)

        {
           //Implement insertion logice here.

        }

        return RedirectToAction("XXXXXX");
    }
```